# Stemming demonyms in Solr (Russian => Russia)

Tags: solr, lucene, stemming

Trying to match queries containing "russia" or "russian" to "Russian Federation" using Solr (as well as other country demonyms, such as "american", "syrian" etc).

What is a good way to handle this without adding synonyms for each country, and without doing much stemming on other words?

Comment: Stemming sounds like the right solution here.  Why are you avoiding stemming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out stemming was the right approach, but the Porter stemmer was too aggressive for some terms.

The [KStemFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/KStemFilterFactory.html) is less aggressive and worked well.